# Unnecessary parameter in useEffect dependency array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm creating an application where users can create and share notes.
To share each other's notes users have to send requests to specific users.
The requests are fetched whenever home is loaded.
However, requests is a context since it is also consumed in the toolbar and requests page to show the presence of the requests
When I'm using `setRequsts` method of the context to set all the requests after home loads, the fetch goes into an infinite loop of `/note`and `/me` URLs, since the `setRequests` method is also provided in the dependency array of `useEffect`
When removed, `useEffect` show missing dependencies. What's the work around?

```
  const {setRequests } = useContext(RequestsContext)
  const [notes, setNotes]    = useState([])
  const [fetched, setFetched] = useState('')
  const { isAuthenticated } = props
  const {page}=useContext(PageContext)
  const [sortBy,setSortBy]=useState('latest')

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetch = async () => {
      try {
        let url = 'http://192.168.56.1:5000/api/v1/note', p, sort
        if (page) p = `?page=${page}&limit=12`
        if (sortBy === 'latest') {
          sort=''
        } else if (sortBy === 'most_liked') {
          sort='&sort=likes'
        }
        const res = await Axios.get(url+p+sort)
        setNotes(res.data.data)
        if (res.data.data.length > 0) {
          setFetched('Y')
        } else {
          setFetched('N')
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      } finally {
        if (isAuthenticated) {
          const fetch = async () => {
            const res = await axios.get(`user/me`)
            if (res.data.data.createdPosts.length > 0) {
              const arr = res.data.data.createdPosts.map(el => el.request)
              console.log(arr)
              setRequests(arr)
            }
          }
          fetch()
        }
      }
    }
    fetch()
  }, [isAuthenticated, /* setRequests, */ page, sortBy])
```

Comment: Please show us where `setRequests` is created and then passed into a `RequestsContext.Provider`

Comment: In the request context file `const RequestsContextProvider = props => {
  const [requests, setRequests] = useState([])
  const [isRequests,setIsRequests]=useState(false)

  const requestHandler = arr => {
    setRequests(arr)
    if (requests.length > 0) {
      setIsRequests(true)
    }
  }
  
  return (
    <RequestsContext.Provider
      value={{ isRequests:isRequests, requests: requests,setRequests: arr => requestHandler(arr) }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </RequestsContext.Provider>
  )
}`

Comment: And consumed in the App file just before placing all the routes`<RequestsContextProvider>
        <Layout>
          {routes}
        </Layout>
      </RequestsContextProvider>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the context provides a technically different `setRequests` function on each render (that have a different address). This causes `useEffect` to fire on each render.

To work around this, you could wrap `setRequests` in a `useCallback()` hook, like so:

```
// ...
const wrappedSetRequests = useCallback(setRequests, []);
// ...

useEffect(() => {
  // do your stuff using 'wrappedSetRequests' instead of setRequests.
}, [ wrappedSetRequests /*...*/ ]);
```